# ERROR : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR como se soluciona?

Tags: php, mysql, api

**buenas tardes, realice un proyecto de una api en php y mysql y la subi a 000Webhost pude testearla mediante postman y funciona perfecto pero mi problema es que al consumir esa api desde el front end realizado en react, me da el error :**  `complejoterrazas.000webhostapp.com/api/user/token:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: ¿Para cuál versión de HTTP programaste (1.0, 1.1 ó 2.0)?

Comment: 1.1 sin embargo configure el header a 2.0 y no funciona